# Where are the cached variables stored after running configure?

Tags: autotools, configure

After I run the configure script, I get a series of output which says "cached". For example:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
...
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
```

Why is it outputting gcc twice here: one with "gcc" and the other "(cached) gcc"? It appears that the script is doing two checks. I thought the script would just check the cache for variables to speed up execution.

Also, where are these cached files stored? According to the autoconf documentation, it says:

> By default, configure uses no cache file, to avoid problems caused by accidental use of stale cache files.

So it seems certain "checks" do get cached by the configure script by default. I have tried running "--config-cache", and the file "config.cache" get created.

I also ran this in my configure script:

```
# optimization flags
if test "x$ac_cv_prog_gcc" = xyes; then
   AC_MSG_CHECKING([AC_CV_PROG_GCC])
   AC_MSG_RESULT("$ac_cv_prog_gcc")
fi
```

The variable "ac_cv_prog_gcc" is nowhere to be found in config.cache though, so I am assuming these cached variables are stored elsewhere. Where are these files located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it outputting gcc twice here: one with "gcc" and the other
>   "(cached) gcc"? It appears that the script is doing two checks.

The script encounters two requests for the same check.  It is smart enough to remember the result of the first one instead of performing an actual check the second time around.  Because it does so, it reports the second time around that the result was drawn from its result cache instead of computed *de novo*.  Even if it is not recording a cache file, it has an in-memory result cache for the duration of the script's run.

It cannot, in general, altogether suppress duplicate checks, because there is often code associated with a check to process the result, and that's not necessarily the same code for each of the redundant checks.

> I
>   thought the script would just check the cache for variables to speed
>   up execution.

Yes, that's exactly what it is doing.  And it is reporting that it has done so, and the result.  This informs you in the event that it uses a value cached during a previous run, or manually entered into the cache, and it can alert you in the event that the cache is manipulated between checks.  In the event that `configure` fails, it may also help you better track where the failure occurred.

> Also, where are these cached files stored? According to the autoconf
>   documentation, it says:
>
> > By default, configure uses no cache file, to avoid problems caused by accidental use of stale cache files.
>
> So it seems certain "checks" do get cached by the configure script by
>   default.

No checks get cached *persistently* by default.  Every result that is cached at all is cached at least for the duration of the `configure` run, however, and if you enable a cache file then it is used for persistent cache storage.

> I have tried running "--config-cache", and the file
>   "config.cache" get created.
>
> I also ran this in my configure script:
>
> ```
> # optimization flags
> if test "x$ac_cv_prog_gcc" = xyes; then
>    AC_MSG_CHECKING([AC_CV_PROG_GCC])
>    AC_MSG_RESULT("$ac_cv_prog_gcc")
> fi
> ```
>
> The variable "ac_cv_prog_gcc" is nowhere to be found in config.cache
>   though, so I am assuming these cached variables are stored elsewhere.

It's not clear to me what you expected to be accomplished by that.  If you want to manually enter a value into the cache then you should use [the `AC_CACHE_VALUE` or `AC_CACHE_CHECK` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Caching-Results.html) for that purpose.  You not appearing to have done so, it is unsurprising that you didn't see the variables cached.

Additionally, it is a bit unclear how you are using the `--config-cache` option.  That option and its siblings apply *on a per-run basis* to control whether a persistent cache is used (both read and written).  The mere presence of a cache file, by any name, is not sufficient for your `configure` script to actually use it on any given run.

> Where are these files located?

You're already looking at it.  It you use the `--config-cache` or `-C` option to your `configure` script then the cache is stored in `config.cache`.  If instead you use the `--cache-file=XXX` option, then the cache is stored in the file you name.

Overall, however, do be aware that [(persistent) caching is probably not what you are looking for](https://autotools.io/autoconf/caching.html).  If you are considering it for a particular need, then I would recommend asking directly about that need, in a separate question.

Comment: That clears how caching works. I tried running configure with "--config-cache" more than once, and it does say "checking for gcc... (cached) gcc" twice meaning it looks in the cached file first. When I do configure without any options (even when config.cache exists from the previous execution of configure --config-cache), it goes back to not checking the cache for the first check, and then using the cache for any subsequent checks.

Comment: Also, I mentioned I couldn't find the variable $ac_cv_prog_gcc in the cached file. I ran a few tests and it always yields a 'yes" with or without the cached file, and the macro AC_CHECK_TOOL(CC, gcc) and AC_PROG_CC is required for it to be set to 'yes'. So ac_cv_prog_gcc must be stored in the in-memory result cache as mentioned in your answer.